# "start with mongrel" doesn't work, but "ruby script/server" works. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In InstantRails:

I click Manage Rails Applications, check Shovell, click Start with Mongrel, visit http://localhost:3000, click Submit a new story!, type login information, click login, the Ruby Console Window closes, I can't login and Firefox outputs Connection Restarted.

or

I click Open Ruby Console Window, type cd Shovell, type ruby script/server, visit http://localhost:3000, click Submit a new story!, type login information, click login, the Ruby Console Window doesn't close, I login and Firefox outputs the form to submit a new story.

I'm wondering why... Do you know?

UPDATED:
log/development.log -> http://pastie.org/802310
stack trace -> http://f.imagehost.org/view/0500/mongrel

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say without more data. Check your error logs -- look for `log/#{RAILS_ENV}.log` (probably `log/development.log` in your case).

---

**Edit:** Additional info was provided by the OP, so I"m updating the answer.

This looks very much like the notorious Rails-not-playing-well-with-MySQL-on-Windows problem. See **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343500/ruby-on-rails-connection-problem)** and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343500/ruby-on-rails-connection-problem) for more info, and try downloading the file [**here**](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails/mysql/bin/libmySQL.dll) for InstantRails.