# Ruby on Rails having a rough time connecting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql-error-1045

I'm having a hard time getting Ruby to connect to mySQL. I can get MYSQL to connect using the mySQL workbench, so that's good.
Here is the error I'm getting when I try to run DBConsole.

```
W:\testMySQL>rails dbconsole
Enter password: ********
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'coffeetowndev'@'localhost' (using pa
ssword: YES)
```

I'm running on a Database on a GoDaddy account, so I'm not able to grant all privledges to that user. I called godaddy, and they swore their 'RoR' department was able to connect using my settings.
Speaking of this, here is the database.yml file.

```
development:
 adapter: mysql
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 port: 3306
 database: coffeetowndev
 pool: 5
 username: coffeetowndev
 password: ********
 hostname: coffeetowndev.db.5850247.hostedresource.com
```

on a related/unrelated note, I'm not able to get mySQL2 gem to install, so I'm using the mySQL one.

edit: entire database.yml file

```
development:
 adapter: mysql
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 port: 3306
 database: coffeetowndev
 pool: 5
 username: coffeetowndev
 password: ********
 hostname: coffeetowndev.db.5850247.hostedresource.com

test:
 adapter: mysql
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 port: 3306
 database: coffeetowntest
 pool: 5
 username: coffeetowntest
 password: ********
 hostname: coffeetowntest.db.5850247.hostedresource.com


production:
 adapter: mysql
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 port: 3306
 database: coffeetown
 pool: 5
 username: coffeetown
 password: ********
 hostname: coffeetown.db.5850247.hostedresource.com
```

Comment: Is there anymore info you want to see? and files? error pages? non-error pages? Also, it appears my call for help was edited out. Is this more of a demanding help kinda-place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the production setting when you deploy to godaddy, instead of the development one?  I'm not experienced with using godaddy for hosting Rails apps, but it's possible they configure all hosted applications to default to the production environment (many rails hosts do).  Therefore, it may not be using the username/password combination you're expecting if it's using a different environment.

You may also want to try testing your credentials by coding up a quick and dirty PHP test script, something like this:

```
$con = mysql_connect("coffeetowndev.db.5850247.hostedresource.com","coffeetowndev","******");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo 'Connected successfully';

mysql_close($con);
```

Also, above it says it's failing but it's trying to use user `'coffeetowndev'@'localhost'`.  You must ensure that you granted permissions to that user using somethign like this:

```
grant select,insert,update,delete on coffeetowndev.* to 'coffeetowndev'@'localhost' identified by ********
```

Comment: oh, I'm not using godaddy for the rails ap, just for the MySQL DB. I plan to push this to heroku, but keep the DB where it is? or is this a horrible idea?

Comment: Ah.  Something is amiss then.  It's trying to use a local database.  Wherever you're running the rails app, it's trying to hook up to a database locally, and is not trying to connect out to coffeetowndev.db.5850247.hostedresource.com from a remote host.  Otherwise, mysql's error message would be: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'coffeetowndev'@'123.123.123.1' (using pa
ssword: YES)`, where 123.123.123.1 is the remote host on which the rails app is running.

Comment: but it knows that the user is 'coffeetowndev' when I enter the password, if I enter it with no password, I get this error: 
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'coffeetowndev'
So, it's hitting the correct DB, bacuse the localhost DB has no info in it whatsoever.

Comment: As far as being a bad idea, the paranoid side of me says yes.  However, many hosts leave mysql open to the internet by default (from a port perspective).  Then, you need to be absolutely sure that you've locked down the user permissions as tight as you can.  You'll probably have to use % as a wildcard in the host segment, as the remote IP will likely change while hosting with Heroku.  So, you'll need something like this: `grant ... on ... to 'coffeetowndev'@'%'`.  My gut reaction though, would be to just have Heroku host your database, rather than trying to host it with Godaddy.

Comment: Try replacing `hostname:` with `host:` in your database.yml file.  Can you paste your entire database.yml file?  What version of rails are you on?

Comment: Try shutting down your local mysql server altogether, and then run the test.  The error you're getting above doesn't indicate anything other than it failed to log into the database.  That doesn't mean the database or any data exists, just that no local user matches the login request.

Comment: Add the echo statement as well (I updated my sample test script above).

Comment: The local server isn't running. I checked my task manager and I see nothing with a mySQL in it.

Comment: @dan-dan-dan Can you try changing each of them from `hostname: ...` to `host: coffeetowntest.db.5850247.hostedresource.com`?

Comment: I believe you will also want to set `reconnect: true`, but that's not causing this issue.

Comment: ok, now I'm getting a rake error... 
rake test:units --trace
rake aborted!
Mysql::Error: query: not connected: SHOW TABLES

Comment: You might be running into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343500/ruby-on-rails-connection-problem

Comment: And somebody else running into the same issue: http://halyph.blogspot.com/2009/08/rails-23-migration-issues-with-mysql_26.html

Comment: so I need an older dll? I swear I'm about 14 seconds away from abandoning ruby and recoding this whole mess in php.

Comment: Yep, it sounds as though there is a compatibility issue and you need to drop in an older version of the dll.  As some of the articles allude to, it's not always easy to get rails running on Windows.  I personally code on mac (most rails people seem to), but linux works well too.  Though honestly, if you're already familiar and comfortable with PHP, you may want to just consider a PHP framework like codeignitor.

Comment: ok, wow. so that completely worked. squawknull, you're my new best friend.

Comment: I do have a mac mini sitting here waiting for me to code the phone app's with. I should use that huh?

Comment: I'd recommend it, just because there are a lot more articles out there on how to get everything up and running on mac than there are for windows, for whatever reason.  The info is out there for Windows, it's just harder to find.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have PHPMyAdmin installed on your SQL server? Typically whenever I create a new users, I'll go through PHPMyAdmin and set up the user with Grant access on the database I'm working with on RoR. Your database.yml looks fine, issue is on the SQL side.

Comment: I do, but I couldn't do a select on the mySQL.users table. I didn't have permission to even do that. I tried to do a grant all for the user 'coffeetowndev' but that error'd out.

Comment: What user were you logged in as when trying to do the grant?

Comment: coffeetowndev. I don't have root user capability from godaddy. bah. (and of course that isn't going to work. I see that now)

Comment: You don't actually need root, you just need `with grant option` specified on your account.  I would expect that you could configure this, or at least configure additional users, from their control panel.